# sed: Copying part of output into a table

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I use G09 to calculate electron proprieties of molecules to use in my master degree. I have a lot of output files and would be good if i put all data that i need into a single file.

My idea is to use `sed` command to select the data and than copy to another file. However it is not working well. I will explain why with 3 examples:

1. This is a part of an output file, i am interested in the value `-382.8066162 (HF=-382.8066162)`:

```
\\Version=ES64L-G09RevD.01\State=1-A'\HF=-382.8066162\RMSD
=4.013e-09\Dipole=0.5408183,-0.047947,0.\Quadrupole=1.1759993,3.185993
9,-4.3619932,-4.1913364,0.,0.\PG=CS [SG(C6H6O2)]\\
```

So, to do that i use the following command in terminal:

```
sed '/HF=.*RMSD/ {s/.*HF=//; s/RMSD.*//; b; }; d' < cs.log |tr -d '\' >> teste
```

And it works very well! But look at others examples of output file.

2. This is a part of other output file, again i am interested in the value `-382.791406`:

```
\\Version=ES64L-G09RevD.01\State=2-A'\HF=-382.79140
6\S2=0.750062\S2-1=0.\S2A=0.75\RMSD=6.390e-09\Dipole=-1.5048474,-0.989
1441,0.\Quadrupole=-14.9615773,1.2107467,13.7508306,9.5370629,0.,0.\PG
=CS [SG(C6H6O2)]\\@
```

The data skipped a line - the value `6` is in the beginning of the next line - and the word after the value also changed (to `S2`).

3. This is a part of other output file, again i am interested in the value `HF=-382.3893192`:

```
\\Version=ES64L-G09RevD.01\State=2-A'\HF=-382
.3893192\S2=0.750091\S2-1=0.\S2A=0.75\RMSD=4.227e-09\Dipole=-1.8688747
,-0.9712963,0.\Quadrupole=-15.2914168,1.4139864,13.8774304,10.0476251,
0.,0.\PG=CS [SG(C6H6O2)]\\@
```

Again, the data `HF=-382.3893192` was separeted into two lines. The first part `HF=-382` and the second part `.3893192`.

How can i fix it?

Thanks

Comment: The number 6 is in the next line of the exemple.

Comment: could a file contain more than 1 desired data match?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. Written and tested in link https://ideone.com/DCfS2a

```
awk '
match($0,/HF=[-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?/){
  print substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3)
}
'  Input_file
```

To pass multiple Input_file(s) to above `awk` program and could take output by appending `> output_file` eg---->

```
awk '
match($0,/HF=[-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?/){
  print substr($0,RSTART+3,RLENGTH-3)
}
'  Input_file1 Input_file2 > output_file
```

***EDIT:*** Its late night here so written and tested this with shown samples Only in ideone site
https://ideone.com/CLG26G to handle newline coming in matched value, there could be other ways as of now I could think of this regex style only.

```
awk'
BEGIN{ RS="" }
{
  while(match($0,/HF=[-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?([\n] +([.][0-9]+))?/)){ 
   val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
   sub(/\n */,"",val)
   print val
   val=""
   $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: Thank you! I have only one observation: In the second exemple part of the data is in the next line. So, the value is not only -382.79140 but -382.791406. Can i fix it?

Comment: @ElyGiancoli,I am sorry I didn't get it. Could you please explain it more what is not working or what is working exactly here?

Comment: I edited the question to add a new example. The real value of HF is splitted into 2 lines.

Comment: @ElyGiancoli, sure please check my edit answer that is working well with new line handling and let me know how it goes then?

Comment: I tested with my file and get: "No such file or directory". I don't understand why.

Comment: @ElyGiancoli, it worked for me for shown samples, could you please make sure you copy pasted it correctly and let me know then.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and tested against your 3rd sample input:

```
awk -v RS= 'match($0,/HF=([^\\]+)/,a){gsub(/\s/,"",a[1]); print a[1]}' file
-382.3893192
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `gnu awk`, you can do this:

```
awk -v RS='\\\\HF=' 'NR>1{gsub(/\\.*|[[:space:]]+/, ""); print}' file
```

```
-382.8066162
-382.791406
-382.3893192
```